# Prevent search engines spider my site in .net mvc?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, robots.txt, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have a asp.net mvc5 application. I want to prevent search engines spider my site in .net mvc.

Is it enough to create robots.txt in my project (Guess it should not be in my solution) with the following code?

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

File structure

```
Solution
--Nuget
--CompanyProject
----Controllers
----Models
----Views
```

Comment: You want to prevent search engine crawler from SEO your site?

Comment: Out of pure curiosity, why would you want such thing?

Comment: I do not want search engines to find the the site. The site is to specific company's and they have the url and login to the site.

Comment: If it's a private site, search engine won't be able to find the site anyway. If there isn't a public link to the site, it will remain hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and place in the root dir of your application.

Here some more info:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/217103

Comment: But root is the project and not the solution? CompanyProject in my first post.

Comment: Yes add to you web project, and set build action as content, or you can do it this way http://www.surinderbhomra.com/Blog/Post/2014/12/13/Dynamic-Robotstxt-file-for-ASPNET-MVC-Sites using controllers, another http://www.onesoft.dk/post/dynamic-robotstxt-with-aspnet-mvc.aspx